# files not uploading in media library wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using word press latest version. It was working fine yesterday but when i login again today. And when i upload image in the media library it gives this error that

**An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later. wordpress**

Also my uploaded images are not showing. I have searched for this. My short tags are also on.

```
[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   1. {main}()            E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\index.php:0

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   2. require() E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\index.php:17

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php:12

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   4. require_once() E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-load.php:37

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   5. require_once() E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-config.php:89

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   6. do_action() E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-settings.php:376

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   7. call_user_func_array: {E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:525}()   E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:525

[25-Mar-2016 11:50:46 UTC] PHP   8. lifeco_setup() E:\designbee\lifeco\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:525
```

this is my log file (Last portion)

Comment: Anything useful in your log files?

Comment: yes i have used all the images in varoius pionts. in database all the images are shown

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i will explain you

Comment: there is option in wordpress where we upload images

Comment: we select a image then it is added in the media library. when i select image then it gives this error that An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later. wordpress

Comment: Did you check your log files?

Comment: how can i check my log files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107387/discussion-between-waqas-jr-developer-and-mike).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: I recommend putting that in your question. Not in the comments. Click the edit button underneath it.

Comment: Make sure your directory have write permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a div outside of the function in my custom post type.